# Lock voting answers for an hour

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting-limits, fastest-gun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

People are often fascinated about how fast are some questions answered on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow made a very good job involving game ideas in the process, but it has at least one downside - IMO:

There are many people (me among them) who are waiting for new questions and rush to respond. Usually among similar answers the one which was posted first is upvoted. Often people tend to answer first with essential things and then improve their answer on the way.

This leads in my opinion to:

1. Rush
2. Poor quality answers in the beginning

Proposed solution:
Lock voting on answers for an hour since the question was asked.

**Update**:
I've seen by many users a suggestion to the OP to not accept an answer immediately, but wait at least an hour. Interesting.

Comment: This has come up [a few times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-gun) before.

Comment: It's not the same. IMO

Comment: No. This will lead to drastic decrease in voting, which is low already.

Comment: or let users vote, but hide the votes for an hour?

Comment: If you post a low quality answer, it will get downvoted. It doesn't matter how quickly you post it. This is a problem that solves itself. **Don't post low quality answers, and downvote those that you see posted.** This feature request moves in exactly the wrong direction. We want to *encourage* good answers to be upvoted and bad answers to be downvoted, not prevent voting altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What is wrong with people rushing to answer a question?  That is a good thing for the answer.  If you don't want to feel rushed don't try to answer questions that are minutes old.
2. If a answer is not of good quality then downvote it.  Although, I normally don't see that. Instead I normally see a quick answer although possibly shorter answer and then an example or links added later.  There is nothing wrong with this.

We want to encourage more voting and this proposal does the opposite by limiting voting.

Comment: >If a answer is not of good quality then downvote it.

Sometimes the answer is partially good, and later a better one appears, but you vote this one, as you don't have alternatives.

Comment: Hmm. I posted nearly the exact same thing as a comment before reading your answer. Guess that means I agree: here's your +1.

Comment: @user167422: If an answer is only "partially good", then why upvote it? No one is forcing you to vote. It's nonsensical to say that "you don't have alternatives".